# Http redirects to https but it's not support in post request method

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

i am newer in firebase and i done firebase hosting first time but facing one issue regarding redirection

firebase hosting redirects http:// to https:// directly but i tried it with post request and it's working fine but posted json data is not there to process over on it

This is my firebase.json redirection rule
http://prntscr.com/han083

here is the screenshot of it

This is my code 
http://prntscr.com/hamzv9

Without https://
http://prntscr.com/hamybm

With https://
http://prntscr.com/hamyxh

Answer (score 0):

This is because a `POST` body won't survive a redirect in general. This may be a small bug on Firebase Hosting's part (or perhaps on the part of whatever tool you're using to make the request) -- the HTTP response should be a 301 redirect, which must then be retried with the full POST body by the client.

In general, for any request other than `GET` you'll need to make sure you properly point at HTTP/HTTPS up front, since redirects don't preserve all request information in most user agents.